# Command to open file in Vim within Emacs and to open Emacs within Vim

Tags: vim, emacs

While working on a file in Emacs, can I open that same file in a window running vim within Emacs?

And can I do the same in Vim? (open emacs with that same file within Vim)

Comment: would opening two windows work?

Comment: It is no matter open on other window or self window. I want to open vim on emacs, emacs on vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch another editor with the currently edited buffer from within Vim:

```
:execute '! emacs' shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)
```

This will keep the file open inside Vim. Some editors (I've tested with nano; as a Vim user I surely don't have Emacs installed :-) detect this and issue a warning. To avoid that, you can first remove the currently editing file from Vim:

```
:execute 'bdelete | ! emacs' shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)
```

I'm sure that something similar can be done in the other direction, too.

Answer (score 3):

This Emacs Lisp function opens the file in the current buffer in Vim, at the same line that point is at:

```
(defun my-open-current-file-in-vim ()
  (interactive)
  (async-shell-command
   (format "gvim +%d %s"
       (+ (if (bolp) 1 0) (count-lines 1 (point)))
       (shell-quote-argument buffer-file-name))))
```